# Polymorphically processing 2 & 3 dimensional objects

Tags: java, beginner, inheritance, polymorphism

It seems there are a lot of "empty containers" (I do not know the correct, technical term) with regards to multiple levels of abstract classes and functional interfaces with little or no code.  Is this the case in real working situations?

Here's the class diagram:

[image: Class Diagram]

And here's the code:

```
package shapeHierarchy;

public interface GetArea 
{
double getArea();
}

package shapeHierarchy;

public interface GetVolume 
{
double getVolume();
}

package shapeHierarchy;

public abstract class Shape implements GetArea
{
}
package shapeHierarchy;

public abstract class TwoDimensionalShape extends Shape
{
}

package shapeHierarchy;

public abstract class ThreeDimensionalShape extends Shape implements GetVolume 
{
}

package shapeHierarchy;

public class Circle extends TwoDimensionalShape
{
private final double radius;

//constructor
public Circle(double radius)
{
    //first subconstructor statement must call superclass constructor
    //"chain up" here
    this.radius = radius;
}

//accesor
public double getRadius()
{
    return radius;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return String.format("%-10s%-10s%n%-10s%-10.1f%n",
            "Shape:", "Circle", "Radius:", getRadius());
}

//fulfill compiler contract with interface
@Override
public double getArea() 
{
    return Math.PI * (getRadius() * getRadius());
}

}

package shapeHierarchy;

public class Triangle extends TwoDimensionalShape
{
private final double height;
private final double base;

//constructor
public Triangle(double height, double base)
{
    //first subconstructor statement must call superclass constructor
    //"chain up" here
    this.height = height;
    this.base = base;
}

//accesors
public double getHeight()
{
    return height;
}

public double getBase()
{
    return base;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return String.format("%-10s%-10s%n%-10s%-10.1f%n%-10s%-10.1f%n",
            "Shape:", "Triangle", "Base:", getBase(), "Height:", getHeight());

}

//fulfill compiler contract with interface
@Override
public double getArea() 
{
    return getHeight() * (getBase() / 2);
}

}


package shapeHierarchy;

public class Square extends TwoDimensionalShape
{
private final double side;

//constructor
public Square(double side)
{
    //first subconstructor statement must call superclass constructor
    //"chain up" here
    this.side = side;
}

//accesor
public double getSide()
{
    return side;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return String.format("%-10s%-10s%n%-10s%-10.1f%n",
            "Shape:", "Square", "Side:", getSide());
}

//fulfill compiler contract with interface
@Override
public double getArea() 
{
    return getSide() * getSide();
}

}

package shapeHierarchy;

public class Sphere extends ThreeDimensionalShape
{
private final double radius;

//constructor
public Sphere(double radius)
{
    //first subconstructor statement must call superclass constructor
    //"chain up" here
    this.radius = radius;
}

//accesors
public double getRadius()
{
    return radius;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return String.format("%-10s%-10s%n%-10s%-10.1f%n",
            "Shape:", "Sphere", "Radius:", getRadius());
}

//fulfill compiler contract with interfaces
@Override
public double getArea() 
{
    return 4.0 * Math.PI * (getRadius() * getRadius());
}

@Override
public double getVolume()
{
    return 4.0 * Math.PI * ((getRadius() * getRadius() * getRadius()) / 3.0);
}
}

package shapeHierarchy;

public class Cube extends ThreeDimensionalShape 
{
private final double side;

//constructor
public Cube(double side)
{
    //first subconstructor statement must call superclass constructor
    //"chain up" here
    this.side = side;
}

//accesors
public double getSide()
{
    return side;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return String.format("%-10s%-10s%n%-10s%-10.1f%n",
            "Shape:", "Cube", "Side:", getSide());
}

//fulfill compiler contract with interfaces
@Override
public double getArea() 
{
    return 6.0 * (getSide() * getSide());
}

@Override
public double getVolume()
{
    return getSide() * getSide() * getSide();
}
}

package shapeHierarchy;

public class Tetrahedron extends ThreeDimensionalShape 
{
private final double edge;

//constructor
public Tetrahedron(double edge)
{
    //first subconstructor statement must call superclass constructor
    //"chain up" here
    this.edge = edge;
}

//accesors
public double getEdge()
{
    return edge;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return String.format("%-10s%-10s%n%-10s%-10.1f%n",
            "Shape:", "Tetrahedron", "Edge:", getEdge());
}

//fulfill compiler contract with interfaces
@Override
public double getArea() 
{
    return Math.sqrt(3.0) * (getEdge() * getEdge());
}

@Override
public double getVolume()
{
    return (getEdge()*getEdge()*getEdge()) / (6.0 * Math.sqrt(2.0));
}
}


package shapeHierarchy;

public class ShapeTest 
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    //create an array of generic shape objects
    Shape[] shapeObject = new Shape[6];

    //populate array with specific, concrete shapes
    shapeObject[0] = new Circle(9.0);
    shapeObject[1] = new Triangle(5.0, 7.0);
    shapeObject[2] = new Square(4.0);
    shapeObject[3] = new Sphere(8.0);
    shapeObject[4] = new Cube(6.0);
    shapeObject[5] = new Tetrahedron(3.0);

    //Ouput Header
    System.out.println("Two and three dimensional objects processed polymorphically\n");

    //generically process each shape object
    for(Shape currentShape : shapeObject)
    {
        System.out.print(currentShape);
        if (currentShape instanceof ThreeDimensionalShape)
        {   
            ThreeDimensionalShape shape3d = (ThreeDimensionalShape) currentShape;
            System.out.printf("%-10s%-10.1f%n",
                    "Area:", shape3d.getArea());
            System.out.printf("%-10s%-10.1f%n",
                    "Volume:", shape3d.getVolume());
        }
        if (currentShape instanceof TwoDimensionalShape)
        {
            TwoDimensionalShape shape2d = (TwoDimensionalShape) currentShape;
            System.out.printf("%-10s%-10.1f%n",
                    "Area:", shape2d.getArea());
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Some of the emptiness is coming from the two interfaces that I think are unnecessary.  Rather than having `GetArea` and `GetVolume` as interfaces, simply have `Shape` specify `getArea()` and have `ThreeDimensionalShape` specify `getVolume()`:

```
public interface Shape {
  public double getArea();
}
public interface ThreeDimensionalShape extends Shape {
  public double getVolume();
}
```

If you wanted a `TwoDimensionalShape` interface, it would indeed be empty, at least right now.  That's okay though.  Maybe you're planning on adding more 2D-specific methods later and know you'll need that layer in the hierarchy.  Maybe you just want to tag things as being 2D--that's called a marker interface and the built-in library uses a few, such as [RandomAccess](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/RandomAccess.html) and [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html).

Answer (score 2):

Some more observations (excluding the nice remarks about the interfaces).

**Naming:** `TwoDimensionalShape` and `ThreeDimensionalShape` are excessively long names, why not just `Shape2D` and `Shape3D` respectively?

**toString():** patterns such as `%-10s%-10s%n%-10s%-10.1f%n%-10s%-10.1f%n` look like if they were written in Brainfuck. More readable alternatives are:

1. Put constant parts inside the pattern, leave formatters only for variables, e.g. `String.format("Shape:   %s%nBase:    %.1f%nHeight:  %.1f%n", getBase(), getHeight());`. Args in `String.format` are usually used for variables.
2. Use a `StringBuilder` to build.

The `"Shape:   %s"` part of this method may be extracted to the super-class. This will avoid repetitions in the concrete classes.

**Expressions** like `6.0 * Math.sqrt(2.0)` should be extracted to static constants. They do not need to be evaluated each time the method is called.

**Remove useless comments** like `//constructor`, `//accessors` and others.

**Validation:** constructor arguments are not validated. If `height`, `base` or `radius` args are negative? Without entering into theoretical discussion, I suppose that negative values will be invalid in the context of your API.

In **main()**, the `shapeObject` array would be initialized better with

```
Shape[] shapeObject = new Shape[] {
  new Circle(9.0), 
  new Triangle(5.0, 7.0), 
  new Square(4.0), 
  new Sphere(8.0),
  new Cube(6.0),
  new Tetrahedron(3.0)
};
```

And you need to invoke `instanceof` only for the case of `ThreeDimensionalShape`, in order to check for `getVolume()` method. `getArea()` is already available for all `Shape` objects.

**Formatting:** opening braces should be moved to the end of their preceeding lines.

Comment: Thank you for all these observations!!!!  I'll learn stringbuilder in the next chapter I see.. All the others I should have known and implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces, as well es classes, are *types* – see [Java Language Specification (JLS), 4.3. Reference Types and Values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3):

> There are four kinds of *reference types*: class types (§8.1), interface types (§9.1), [...]

So, their names should be similar to class names – see [Code Conventions for the Java <sup>TM</sup> Programming Language, 9 - Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html):

> Class names should be nouns. [...]

Hence, as mentioned by MattPutnam in his answer, `getArea` and `getVolume` fit better to method names.

---

- I'd use the variables `radius`, `height`, `base`, `side` instead of the associated getter methods in your area and volume calculations.
- I'd omit mathematically unnecessary parentheses in your calculations for easier reading.

E.g.:

```
return 4.0 * Math.PI * radius * radius * radius / 3.0;
```

instead of:

```
return 4.0 * Math.PI * ((getRadius() * getRadius() * getRadius()) / 3.0);
```

Comment: I was under the assumption that using getter methods preserved data encapsulation, data hiding, etc.

Comment: @BiancaRuiz In principle, yes, but that doesn't include encapsulating or hiding the data from/within your own (internal) class implementation. It's meant for (external) users of your class.